# How to stop regex match if word is found?

Tags: php, regex, perl

I have text like this:

```
TEXT 786
OPQ RTS

APPENDIX A 

TITLE 

TEXT 123 
ABC EFG 

APPENDIX B

TEXT 456
HIJ KLM
```

and

```
TEXT 786
OPQ RTS

APPENDIX A 

TITLE 

TEXT 123 
ABC EFG 

TEXT 456
HIJ KLM
```

I'm trying to use regex to extract all the text starting from `APPENDIX A` to `APPENDIX B` if `APPENDIX B` is present otherwise from `APPENDIX A` until the end (i.e., `HIJ KLM`). Also, `APPENDIX A` must appear within 15 words before `TITLE`. This is what I'm come up with so far:

```
(\b(?:appendix)(?:.){0,15}(?:title)(?:.*)(?:appendix){0,1})/is
```

Problem is, the capture does not stop at `APPENDIX B` if `APPENDIX B` is there, it always captures until the end.

Comment: Are you using php or perl?

Comment: PERL-compatible regex in PHP

Comment: Note that the description says "_within 15 **words** before TITLE_" (emphasis mine), while regex uses 15 characters, `.{0,15}`.  I went with what the code says in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use alternation for the optional part

```
perl -0777 -wlnE'
    @m = /(appendix .{0,15} title (?: .*?appendix\s\w+ | .*) )/xsig; 
    say for @m
' input.txt
```

with `/g` so to match all sections within `appendix` markers.

Or capture with multiple groups, one for the optional item, then test for it and use accordingly

```
perl -0777 -wne'
    @m = /(appendix .{0,15} title) (.*? appendix\s\w+)? (.*)/xsi;
    print join "", ($m[1] ? @m[0,1] : @m[0,2])
' input.txt
```

This works because `$2` *is* created for the second `(` even if there is no match.

With yet more capture groups you can filter in the second case, `? grep { defined } @m`.  If there may be multiple `appendix`-sections better use `while` with `$N` variables in this approach

```
while (/(appendix.{0,15}title)(.*?appendix\s\w+)?(.*)/sig) {
    my $appx_section = ($2) ? $1.$2 : $1.$3;
    ...
}
```

since one big `@m` with all captures would need a little analysis.

All these print the desired output in both cases, including multiple `appendix`-sections.

I've wrapped it in one-liners for ready testing. The code works in a Perl script as it stands.

Comment: How would I stop match at the first APPENDIX B, if the text has more than one APPENDIX B?

Comment: @user4951834  That's what it should do, by `.*?appendix` (non-greedy `?`) ... does it not?

Comment: Thanks, going to give this a try.

Comment: @user4951834  Simplified and rearranged the post

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45741514/manipulate-and-filter-a-large-string-with-similar-pattern-in-javascript/45742379#45742379) as an inspiration.
Basically, I`ve splitted the text by line-break, then iterated on each line and converted it into blocks.

These blocks are what you want. :]

I'm not familiar with perl, but the idea should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just like this, where $var is your string.

```
if ( $var=~m#(APPENDIX A.{0,15}TITLE.*?(?:APPENDIX B|$))#s )
{
    print $1."\n";
}
else 
{

    print "failed\n";
}
```

your problem was this "(?:.*)(?:appendix){0,1})"  greedy matching plus a {0,1} which just means it will always just take the lot because regex is greedy. .*? is non-greedy e.g., just take the minimum possible to still make the match